# Tikz: midway label on a bended line

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my problematic code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (0,0)  to [bend left=20] (3,3) node[midway] {midway label};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I wanted to put a label midway of the line, but instead the label is at `(0,0)`.

If I remove `[bend left=20]`, the line is not bent, and the label still misplaced.
If I remove `to` and replace it by `--`, then it works fine, but my line is not bent any more.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (3,3) node[midway] {midway label};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Works fine.

The problem occurs with MacTeX 2011 and MacTeX 2012.

Comment: Hi Loick, welcome to TeX.sx! It's generally preferred to post full compilable examples instead of just snippets. And a tip: Inline code (like the `[bend left=20]` in your post) can be formatted by enclosing them in backticks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should move `node[midway] {midway label}` before the last coordinate.

Some examples:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (0,0)  to [bend left=20] node[midway] {midway label}(3,3) ;
\draw[xshift=4cm]  (0,0)  to [bend left=20] node[midway,left] {midway label}(3,3) ;
\draw[xshift=6cm]  (0,0)  to [bend left=20] node[midway,right] {midway label}(3,3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (0,0)  to [bend left=20] node[sloped,midway,above] {midway label}(3,3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can left be set as 3/4 of the positon (like sliding little bit to the right)?

Comment: @alper: sure, you can play with the right keys to achieve the desired result. If you mean the label, then use `pos=` rather than `midway` (which is a shortcut for `pos=0.5`). If you mean the bending, then play with the angle.

Answer (score 17):

You can also use the `pos=<value from 0 to 1>` key (see manual section 16.8) to specify where on your curve the node should be. A little example illustrating this for 0.1 increments from 0 to 1:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {0,0.1,...,1}
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \draw  (0,0)  to [bend left=20] node[pos=\x,fill=red,circle,inner sep=2pt] {} (3,3) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]