# how to locate the text besides the center of the line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I used the code below to add the text besides the line, however, it is very near to the bottom node, I wish to add the text besides the center of the line. May someone help me on this?

The code is :

```
\path [line] (s8) -- node [left]{hotel}(s9);
```

Now the result is:

[image]

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for tikz as there are numerous libraries.

Comment: Have a look also to the answers of [Tikz: midway label on a bended line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64252/tikz-midway-label-on-a-bended-line).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the position either by description such as `midway`, or by `pos=` syntax, and control the node position by `above`, `right`, etc.

[image]

### Notes:

There are numerous other options, refer to the tikz/pgf manual.

### Code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, blue, -latex]
    \draw (0,0) -- (3,-2) node [red, below] {A};
    \draw (2,0) -- (5,-2) node [red, midway, right] {A};
    \draw (4,0) -- (7,-2) node [red, pos=0.1, above] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```