# How to draw an arrow from a node to itself with a label lay above the arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I know how to draw an arrow from a node to itself:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {};
    \draw[->] (a) to[in=150, out=30, looseness=4.8] (a);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: An arrow from a node to itself]

I also know how to draw a straight arrow with a label above:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node (b) at (1,0) {};
    \draw[->] (a) -- (b) node [midway,above] {xxxx};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: A straight arrow with a label above]

But how to draw an arrow from a node to itself with a label above the arrow like this?

[image: An arrow from a node to itself with a label above the arrow]

Comment: Your codes are not compilable even if I add appropriate packages. You must have a label for each node, i.e. `\node (a) at (0,0) {A};` or `\node (a) at (0,0) {};` instead of `\node (a) at (0,0);`.

Comment: @L.F. I approved your edit suggestion. However, there is no need to add image description because they are not shown at all ;)

Comment: @JouleV OK, I will just use "enter image description here" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place `node[midway...` *before* the last node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
\draw[->] (a) to[in=150,out=30,looseness=4.8] node[midway,above] {xxxx} (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Further reference: [Tikz: midway label on a bended line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64252/156344).